# What is the ideal data structure (Priority Queue seems insufficient) for frontier in Uniform-cost search?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, a-star

Very often we need to discard repeated states, as stated in [uniform-cost search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search).

```
  if n is in frontier with higher cost
  replace existing node with n
```

Priority Queue doesn't provide an interface for search an item for its priority and then update it. I am surprised I cannot find any resource regarding this, any one can offer help please.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a Priority Search Queue.

> A priority search queue efficiently supports the
>   opperations of both a search tree and a priority queue. A Binding is a
>   product of a key and a priority. Bindings can be inserted, deleted,
>   modified and queried in the queue (usually in logarithmic time), and the binding with the
>   least priority can be retrieved in constant time.

Here is an [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/PSQueue/1.1/doc/html/Data-PSQueue.html) in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Many Priority Queue implementations allow keeping some reference to queue element and then use it to delete/update this element.

You can easily keep such references if you implement Priority Queue as a binary search tree. For Binary Heap this is possible, but more difficult: you'll need to update references for all elements, moved upheap or downheap.

There are Priority Queue implementations, allowing efficient update of elements when used with algorithms like uniform-cost search. See [Pairing heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) and [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get away with a regular priority queue for uniform-cost search.

You can insert a new, better (node, cost) pair without deleting the old one. You will always process the newly inserted entry first (because it's better) and processing the older entry will effectively be a no-op. The downside is that you may end up with O(E) elements in the priority queue (instead of O(V)).